# Flink job failed with "Checkpoint Coordinator is suspending."

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I ran a flink job and it failed after 18 hours. Failure message: Checkpoint Coordinator is suspending.

Checkpoint screenshot:
[image: Checkpoint screenshot]

Job overview screenshot:
[image: Job overview screenshot]

Here is the job manager logs:

```
2020-10-10 13:53:10,636 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: kafkaSource -> Timestamps/Watermarks -> Process (1/1) (c38419ece8208c1ef2948087f2b84dd0) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.Exception: Could not perform checkpoint 3265 for operator Source: kafkaSource -> Timestamps/Watermarks -> Process (1/1).
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.triggerCheckpoint(StreamTask.java:785)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$triggerCheckpointAsync$3(StreamTask.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.run(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:87)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:261)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:485)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:469)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:708)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$CheckpointingOperation.executeCheckpointing(StreamTask.java:1394)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.checkpointState(StreamTask.java:974)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$performCheckpoint$5(StreamTask.java:870)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.performCheckpoint(StreamTask.java:843)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.triggerCheckpoint(StreamTask.java:776)
    ... 11 more
```

I don't know what cause this problem.

Comment: What do you see in the logs? Both the Job Manager and Task Manager logs may have valuable clues.

Comment: Voted to close as it is unlikely to be reproduced or resolved without further information as requested last year.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when your application is trying to checkpoint, and at that time the checkpoint coordinator (Job Manager) shuts down due to some reason, and the checkpoint could not be completed. The reason for the shutdown can be due to multiple reasons, for example, you started a new deployment, you canceled the job, the job had to exit due to some runtime exception, etc.